# How to prevent multiple push of UIViewController in swift?

Tags: ios, swift, navigation

When I am tapping multiple times very quickly on next button then controller is stacked more clearly pushed multiple times, the problem is we need to click multiple times on back button to land on the previous screen.

next button code

```
guard  let controller = UIStoryboard(name: "Filepreview", bundle: nil).instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "FilepreviewVC") as? PreviewFileViewController else {return}
                            self.navigationController?.pushViewController(controller, animated: true)
```

Comment: How about disabling the next button after it is pressed, and only enabling it in `viewDidAppear` (or some other method that will be called when you come back from the pushed VC)?

Comment: I didn't disabled the button, actually same action is also performed in table view row selction

Comment: Well, how about you do then? Or at least, make it "not work" after 1 press.

Comment: enabling next button on viewWillAppear

Answer (score 1):

Don't allow the user to push the button multiple times!

This can be done by disabling the button just before you push the new VC:

```
nextButton.isEnabled = false
```

If you don't want the user to see that the button is disabled, or that the trigger for the push isn't something that can be disabled, just use a private property to keep track of your own "disabled" state:

```
private var nextButtonDisabled = false

// ...

// when you want to push the new VC, check nextButtonDisabled first!
if nextButtonDisabled {
    return
}
nextButtonDisabled = false
// push new VC here
```

And when the user navigates back, `viewDidAppear` will be called, so you can enable the `nextButton` in `viewDidAppear`:

```
nextButton.isEnabled = true
// or
nextButtonDisabled = false
```

Alternatively, do this in the `navigationController(_:didShow:animated:)` delegate method.

```
self.navigationController?.delegate = self

// ...

extension MyViewController : UINavigationControllerDelegate {
    func navigationController(_ navigationController: UINavigationController, didShow viewController: UIViewController, animated: Bool) {
        if viewController == self {
            nextButtonDisabled = false
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: how to use this navigationController(_:didShow:animated:) ?

Comment: actually I have to implement this with table view row selection

Comment: @AJ No problem, just use the private property approach. And `return` immediately if it is true in `didSelectRowAt`.

Answer (score 0):

Subclass `UINavigationController` and override this function

```
public override func pushViewController(_ viewController: UIViewController, animated: Bool) {
    if
        let currentTopVC = viewControllers.last as? PreviewFileViewController,
        previewFileVC = viewController as? PreviewFileViewController,
        currentTopVC.file.id == previewFileVC.file.id {
        return
    }

    super.pushViewController(viewController, animated: animated)
}
```

I'm assuming here that there is some kind of identity in `PreviewFileViewController` beyond the type, so there could be two instances stacked on each other if they preview different files. If only one preview is possible you can omit the last line before `return`.

Answer (score 0):

```
@IBAction func Submit(_ sender: Any) {
    for _ in 0..<10 {
        DispatchQueue.main.async {
            guard self.navigationController?.viewControllers.contains(where: {$0.isKind(of: TestVC.self)}) == false else { return }
            let vc = self.storyboard?.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "TestVC") as! TestVC
            vc.view.backgroundColor = self.generateRandomColor()
            self.navigationController?.pushViewController(vc, animated: true)
        }
    }
}
```

guard self.navigationController?.viewControllers.contains(where: {$0.isKind(of: TestVC.self)}) == false else { return } use this to check whether a viewcontroller is already in stack or not.